# Programmatically Checking if a Passcode Lock is Set

Tags: ios, security, ipad, locking

Since my app would be dealing with sensitive data of the user, I would like to know if there is a way I can check from my app whether there is a Passcode Lock set in iOS.

The reason I need to check this is because say if the user has in the app some information and then keeps it on the table and goes out for a couple of minutes. The iPad/iPhone by default, goes to standby mode. If a passcode lock had been set, only when the correct passcode is entered, would anyone be able to use the ipad. This would provide an additional security measure to prevent any passerby to view the sensitive data from the app.

So basically, I would like my app to check whether the passcode lock is set and if not prompt the user to do it.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why don't you add a locking mechanism to your app so that the user can lock it without locking the whole iPad instead?

Comment: the case I need it would be when the user keeps the ipad down and goes away for a while on an emergency or something... that time, the ipad would automatically lock after a while(due to its default behaviour)... so to prevent anyone other than the user to just unlock the ipad and see the sensitive data on the app, I needed to check whether the passcode lock has been set for the ipad and if not, prompt the user to set a passcode lock...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the File Protection section on [The Application Runtime Environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html).  File protection requires the user to have passcode lock setting enabled and a valid passcode set.  If you your application writes/creates and file, use the [NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete) option. If your application doesn't use any files, then create a dummy file and enable the protection.

Comment: what if the passcode lock is disabled? Are you still able to perform this file protection locks manually? I had watched the wwdc 2010 regarding the securing applications data but it assumes you have passcode lock on. How can you enforce this?

Comment: This doesn't work any more. Reading around suggests it hasn't worked since at least iOS 5.

Answer (score 10):

With iOS 8, there is now a way to check that the user has a passcode set. **This code will crash on iOS 7.**

Objective-C:

```
-(BOOL) deviceHasPasscode {
    NSData* secret = [@"Device has passcode set?" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"LocalDeviceServices",  (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount: @"NoAccount", (__bridge id)kSecValueData: secret, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly };

    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, NULL);
    if (status == errSecSuccess) { // item added okay, passcode has been set            
        SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Swift:

```
func deviceHasPasscode() -> Bool {
    let secret = "Device has passcode set?".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let attributes = [kSecClass as String:kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecAttrService as String:"LocalDeviceServices", kSecAttrAccount as String:"NoAccount", kSecValueData as String:secret!, kSecAttrAccessible as String:kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly]

    let status = SecItemAdd(attributes, nil)
    if status == 0 {
        SecItemDelete(attributes)
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: is this approved by apple ?

Comment: It should be okay because it is using standard keychain calls.

Answer (score 6):

Since `iOS 9`, there is a flag `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` in LocalAuthentication framework.

```
+ (BOOL)isPasscodeEnabled
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

    BOOL passcodeEnabled = [context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&error];

    if(passcodeEnabled) {
        NSLog(@"Passcode enabled.");
        return YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"Passcode NOT enabled: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    return NO;
}
```

Since `iOS 8` there have been another flag for checking if `TouchID` is enabled:

```
+ (BOOL)isTouchIdEnabled
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

    BOOL touchIDEnabled = [context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error];

    if(touchIDEnabled) {
        NSLog(@"TouchID enabled.");
        return YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"TouchID NOT enabled: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.iOS solution for iOS 8...note I call `SecKeyChain.Remove(secRecord)` on every check.  I found if I didn't include this I could get the device into an odd state where it was trying to authenticate with the user on every call to `SecKeyChain.Add(secRecord)`

```
private bool DetectIfPasscodeIsSet ()
{
    var secRecord = new SecRecord (SecKind.GenericPassword) {
        Label = "Check if passcode is set",
        Description = "Check if passcode is set",
        Account = "Check if passcode is set",
        Service = "Check if passcode is set",
        Comment = "Check if passcode is set",
        ValueData = NSData.FromString ("Check if passcode is set"),
        Generic = NSData.FromString ("Check if passcode is set")
    };
    SecKeyChain.Remove (secRecord); 
    secRecord.AccessControl = new SecAccessControl (SecAccessible.WhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly);
    var status = SecKeyChain.Add (secRecord);
    if (SecStatusCode.Success == status) {
        SecKeyChain.Remove (secRecord);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed this!