# Check for device lock and validate certificate

Tags: ios, ipad, security

For one of my iOS apps I need to check two things:

- Is there an active device lock (pass code)
- Has the device lock been triggered by the correct authority / certificate (e.g. my own certificate). This is required to assure specific security guidelines.

For the first part of my question I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195643) answer - which is sufficient for me. How would you accomplish the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

First of all the correct question is not about validation of a certificate. It's about validation of meta information placed within a configuration profile (which in my case provides security guidelines for the device lock).

You have to create a custom CA and issue one certificate. The issued certificate has to be placed within your app, the custom CA's certificate goes into the configuration profile.

If the configuration profile is installed it is possible to check whether the certificate within the app binary was signed with the root certificate placed in the configuration profile.

It's not the most secure solution, but definitely a way to go.

--

[This](https://devforums.apple.com/message/665263#665263) post put me into the right direction (Apple Developer Account required).