# Can I check whether the user has set a passcode?

Tags: ios, security

We have an app that stores sensitive data.  We've enabled file protection, but that only has an effect if the user has set a passcode.  If the user hasn't set a passcode, we need to show an alert telling the user to do that, and then not to load the rest of the app.

Basically we're in the exact situation as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191592), and my question is exactly their question.  But the accepted answer there is "enable file protection", which is not an answer to that question, or to this one; I'm already enabling file protection and it doesn't tell me whether they've set a passcode or not.

So is it possible to check, and if so, how?  Ideally we'd like to check whether the user has set a long passcode or a simple one, and if they've only set a simple one we would warn them to set a proper one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With iOS 8, there is now a way to check that the user has a passcode set. **This code will crash on iOS 7.**

Objective-C:

```
-(BOOL) deviceHasPasscode {
    NSData* secret = [@"Device has passcode set?" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"LocalDeviceServices",  (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount: @"NoAccount", (__bridge id)kSecValueData: secret, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly };

    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, NULL);
    if (status == errSecSuccess) { // item added okay, passcode has been set            
        SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Swift:

```
func deviceHasPasscode() -> Bool {
    let secret = "Device has passcode set?".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let attributes = [kSecClass as String:kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecAttrService as String:"LocalDeviceServices", kSecAttrAccount as String:"NoAccount", kSecValueData as String:secret!, kSecAttrAccessible as String:kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly]

    let status = SecItemAdd(attributes, nil)
    if status == 0 {
        SecItemDelete(attributes)
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Is it working on iOS 11 (beta)? We are facing issue on iOS 11(beta)

Answer (score 11):

There is an official answer to this question with iOS 9:

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&authError]) 
{
    // Device has either passcode enable (or passcode and touchID)
} 
else 
{
    // Device does not have a passcode
    // authError can be checked for more infos (is of type LAError)
}
```

A link to [Apple's LAContext class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html)

A note: *LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication* is a constant available in iOS 9 only. iOS 8 had *LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics* available. It can be used to achieve some results but these do not answer your question.

Comment: Good Answer, works on iOS10. Same thing in Swift3: `func deviceHasPasscodeEnabled()->Bool
    {
        let myContext = LAContext()
        var authError:NSError? = nil
        
        if (myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &authError))
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }`