# Programatically Checking if a Passcode Lock is Set on iOS 7

Tags: ios, security, ios7, xamarin

I realized passcode detection as described here - 
[Programatically Checking if a Passcode Lock is Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191592/programatically-checking-if-a-passcode-lock-is-set) , but it only works on iOS 8 and higher.

App crash on this line`secRecord.AccessControl = new SecAccessControl (SecAccessible.WhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly);`
Is it possible programmatically check passcode status on iOS 7 ?
I didn't found any information about this.

Comment: Seems that the code was introduced with iOS 8 and therefor not available in iOS 7. I've looked at the documentation and there does not seem to be any way to do this before iOS 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No You cant.From the documentation:

**kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock**

The data in the keychain item cannot be accessed after a restart until the device has been unlocked once by the user.

After the first unlock, the data remains accessible until the next restart. This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by background applications. Items with this attribute migrate to a new device when using encrypted backups.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly**

The data in the keychain item cannot be accessed after a restart until the device has been unlocked once by the user.

After the first unlock, the data remains accessible until the next restart. This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by background applications. Items with this attribute do not migrate to a new device. Thus, after restoring from a backup of a different device, these items will not be present.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**kSecAttrAccessibleAlways**

The data in the keychain item can always be accessed regardless of whether the device is locked.

This is not recommended for application use. Items with this attribute migrate to a new device when using encrypted backups.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly**

The data in the keychain can only be accessed when the device is unlocked. Only available if a passcode is set on the device.

This is recommended for items that only need to be accessible while the application is in the foreground. Items with this attribute never migrate to a new device. After a backup is restored to a new device, these items are missing. No items can be stored in this class on devices without a passcode. Disabling the device passcode causes all items in this class to be deleted.

Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

**kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly**

The data in the keychain item can always be accessed regardless of whether the device is locked.

This is not recommended for application use. Items with this attribute do not migrate to a new device. Thus, after restoring from a backup of a different device, these items will not be present.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked**

The data in the keychain item can be accessed only while the device is unlocked by the user.

This is recommended for items that need to be accessible only while the application is in the foreground. Items with this attribute migrate to a new device when using encrypted backups.

This is the default value for keychain items added without explicitly setting an accessibility constant.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly**

The data in the keychain item can be accessed only while the device is unlocked by the user.

This is recommended for items that need to be accessible only while the application is in the foreground. Items with this attribute do not migrate to a new device. Thus, after restoring from a backup of a different device, these items will not be present.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.