# Detect passcode lock state from Home screen

Tags: ios, notifications, passwords, darwin, springboard

I would like to know if there is any way (should be approved on Appstore) to detect when device passcode is activated on Home screen.

Basically, my app would like to know those phone events:

1. device screen turn on/off
2. phone lock/unlock (by Auto-Lock setting / press Power button)
3. **passcode activate (by Require Passcode setting)**

As far as I research, I could achieve 1 & 2 by combine `Darwin Notification Center` & `notify_get_state` with 4 events:

```
 com.apple.springboard.lockstate
 com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete
 com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen
 com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus
```

**The problem I get is those events only tell me about lock / unlock state, not passcode state.** Mean that if you require passcode after 5 mins, you can lock/unlock phone without passcode in first 4 mins.

I also know to there is a way to get both lock state & passcode state, by using `SBGetScreenLockStatus(port, &locked, &passcode)`. 
But it's using private framework so it would be rejected by Apple.

From this topic ([Programatically Checking if a Passcode Lock is Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191592/programatically-checking-if-a-passcode-lock-is-set)) I only get if passcode is set on phone or not.

UPDATE: What I found is there is an event called back when passcode is in effected. 
`com.apple.mobile.keybagd.lock_status` but can't find any document about it. And it doesn't changed value when i use `notify_get_state`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find some private API to get it. However, most likely these won't be approved by Apple. There is a chance that they will miss it. However, they reject apps based on private API usage.

Comment: Exactly. That why I'm researching if is there anyway to achieve that with public API. But so far there is no result.

Comment: @nahung89 I would recommend looking into WiFi, Bluetooth and other networking API. It could be that they have some externalities which you can check to detect that a device was turned off. Maybe they switch to another mode or something like that.